# Delete and Update Query Using Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following select statement:

```
select  *
from    (   select  q.*,
                qg.index_min as groupIndexMin,
                qg.index_max as groupIndexMax,
                fo.form_condition,
                fo.form_array,fo.form_index
            from question_group qg, question q
            right join form fo on q.form_id = fo.form_id
            where q.form_id=14 and
                 (q.question_group_id=qg.question_group_id and q.question_type_id NOT IN(12))
            order by question_order) m
 left join (select  r.response_text,
                    r.response_id,
                    r.response_index,
                    f.*,
                    a.*
             from   response r
             right outer join field f on r.field_id=f.field_id and r.response_index=5
             right outer join application a on r.application_id=a.application_id
             right outer join user u on a.user_id=u.user_id
             where  (a.application_id=70 and u.user_id=47)) n on m.field_id = n.field_id
order by m.question_order ;
```

Now I need,

1. Delete Query : for the above select query using same conditions the record will be delete where response_index=5.
2. Update Query : Suppose, if I delete response_index=5, then remaining response_index will be update. For example response_index=6 => response_index=5  and response_index=7 => response_index=6 like that.

Please help me.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved!!!

Comment: @Velmurugan . . . I have removed the extraneous database products from the tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Please format the query in multiple lines, otherwise it is very difficult to read.